# Is it save to remove Main Menu?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, statusbar

I'm writing an agent (so no dock icon or menu bar) based around a status item. The Main Menu never gets displayed. Can I remove it without problems?

Comment: It would take about 5 seconds to actually test this.

Comment: I can remove it but I'm worrying about compatibility with older/newer versions of OS X or occasions when the main menu gets display somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user could want to use any keyboard shortcuts while interacting with your status item, then you'll want to keep the main menu around. Even when it's not visible, an app's main menu is the provider of keyboard shortcuts like Copy and Paste.

Learned from hard experience.